# How to define color of curly brace, semi-colon etc. in gedit using XML

Tags: xml, gedit

I have never used `XML` before, how do I `define` `color` of `curly-brace` or `semi-colon`, etc using XML.

I copied the Tango xml and have been trying all sorts of stuff;

```
<color name="red"                   value="#FF0000"/>

<style name="brace"               foreground="red" bold="true"/>
<style name="def:{"               foreground="red" bold="true"/>
<style name="def:'{'"             foreground="red" bold="true"/>
```

It does not work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to really understand what your need is here, but I'll say that XML is a markup language, you are not supposed to put style information in it. Xml is about describing the data you are working on.

If you want to use colors and such, associate your XML file to a CSS stylesheet for example, or produce an HTML output using XSL stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but the link below has lots of examples of how to set various color styles in gedit XML style files, though I'm not sure which one would work for curly-brace and semicolon; maybe `def:special-char`, `def:builtin`, or `def:keyword`:

[gedit-themes](https://github.com/mig/gedit-themes)